# Running Cypress E2E Tests in Kubernetes Pod - Parallel Execution

Tags: kubernetes, parallel-processing, cypress

I have cypress E2E tests currently running in the Kubernetes Pods and using the docker container setup. Im trying to run these tests in parallel. Previously I have been using the plugin https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action to do that that takes args to do that, but this time I'm unsure of how to do it.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to run your Cypress tests in parallel in K8s Cluster:

1. As a first step, you can set up multiple stages that run in parallel, and all of these Cypress stages can run in the same pod without issue.
2. You can use cypress-parallel library to run multiple tests in parallel on the same pods.
3. If you want to run the Cypress tests in separate pods, you need to create pods for each parallel stage, then run your Cypress script using tags or different scripts.

you can refer to this blog , i found it very useful : https://medium.com/@iamsanjeevkumar/run-cypress-test-in-parallel-without-cypress-dashboard-1c0c33377628